# Set private var and read value in method

Tags: java, testing, groovy, spock

I'm trying to set private variable in class in my Spock test and read this value in class method, but it's not working.

Template class

```
public class Template {
    private String finalMessage;

    public String getMessage() {
        return finalMessage;
}
```

TemplateTest.groovy

```
    given: "A template"
        Template template = Mock()

    when: "setting field"
        String templ = "<APP/>aaaa";

        Field f2 = Template.class.getDeclaredField("finalMessage");
        f2.setAccessible(true);

        f2.set(template ,templ);

    then: "tags set contains all tags"
        System.out.println(f2.get(template));
        System.out.println(template.getMessage());
```

Output

```
<APP/>aaaa
null
```

I am mocking this Template object because it's connecting to database and I don't want use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `Template` instance is a **mock** and you have not stubbed the `getMessage()` method, it is returning `null`. This is the default behaviour of mock objects. The code in the actual `getMessage()` method is never called. You have to stub the methods to return what you want them to. You can probably stub it in such a way that the actual code is called, but that depends on the mocking framework you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure (I never worked with Groovy), but it's propably because you didn't assign any value to the `finalMessage`. I think it should be `private String finalMessage = //The string`. But as I said, I don't know Groovy, so, as Priyesh said, it may be a bug in Groovy...

Comment: It is being set through reflection in `f2.set()` line. But the `Mock()` is the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I just learned lil' bit of Groovy, so I understand it better now.